# import ssl certificate in Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, ssl-certificate

i have the following issue:

I obtain a free certificate from comodo (90 days) for my glassfish web application and then i have imported the certs into glassfish 3.1 by following http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/

I have also modify the domain.xml file by replacing the alias s1as with my certificate alias and the file keystore.jks with the server.keystore....but when i try to access my web application with https protocol i got the following log error:

[#|2012-10-12T14:41:18.828+0200|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.Gr
izzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=25;_ThreadName=http-thread-pool-443(1);|GRIZZLY00
07: SSL support could not be configured!
java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificat
e or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.

Please help me..i know that here i can find the solution to my issue...

Answer (score 28):

Unfortunately I don`t have enough reputation to post images of glassfish console admin, but let me try to help somebody just using text.

**NOTE1:** The configuration was done on Ubuntu 12.04 server and glassfish 3.1.2

Comodo gives you 4 files

- your_domain.key (your private key)
- your_domain.crt (your public key)
- PositiveSSLCA2.crt (CA public key)
- AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt (CA public key)

Import every public key into the file cacerts.jks. To do that merge the public key files in one file:

**NOTE2:** The order of the files DOES matter.

```
cat your_domain.crt PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt  > all.crt
```

Now import them using keytool:

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file all.crt -keystore cacerts.jks
```

Create a p12 file with your private key:

**NOTE3:** You can use the same password for every file to make things easier.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in all.crt -inkey your_domain.key -out your_domain.p12 - name your_alias -CAfile PositiveSSLCA2.crt -caname immed
```

**NOTE4:** Don`t forget you alias (**your_alias**), you will need to reference it in glassfish admin console later.

Now import the private key using keytool:

```
keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore keystore.jks -srckeystore your_domain.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass changeit -alias your_alias
```

Now your **keystore.jks** (with your private keys) and your **cacerts.jks** (with you public key) are ready to me used. If you want to check if everything is ok run:

```
keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks
keytool -list -keystore cacerts.jks
```

Go to the glassfish admin console and find the session:

- Configurations->server-config->HTTP Service->Http Listeners->http-listener-2

Go to the SSL tab and change the **Certificate NickName** to **your_domain**.

Restart Glassfish server.

Comment: what is the "immed" part of "-caname immed"

Comment: where do i put the `keystore.jks file`?

Comment: when I `cat` my certificates it didn't add a new line after the first certificate. I had to edit it manually. Each certificate ends with a `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` then a newline and only then the next `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`. Otherwise it wasn't recognizes as a valid certificate.

Comment: Note that the command in NOTE3: is faulty. It says: .... - name ... and should be ... -name ... There is one space to much.

Comment: Note you can change non-standard JKS format to PKCS12 (therefore ignoring openssl part) by using command keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore <your JKS store> -destkeystore <your JKS store> -deststoretype pkcs12

Answer (score 4):

**Preconditions:**

- installed keytool and GlassFish 4.x (with default keystore password `changeit`)
- your source keystore used to generate CSR

  - e.g. `~/mySourceKeystore.jks` with password `myPassword` and private key with alias `myAlias`
- your valid certificate (obtained from CA)

  - e.g. `~/myCertificate.crt` with password `myPassword` and alias `myAlias`
- certificate of CA (obtained from CA)

  - e.g. `~/AwesomeCA.crt`

**Here are all steps how to import SSL certificate into GlassFish:**

1. Navigate to `GLASSFISH-HOME/domains/domain1/config`
2. Import your source keystore (with private key) into GlassFish keystore:

   ```
   $ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore ~/mySourceKeystore.jks -destkeystore keystore.jks`
   Enter destination keystore password: changeit
   Enter source keystore password: myPassword
   Entry for alias server successfully imported.
   Import command completed:  1 entries successfully imported, 0 entries failed or cancelled
   ```
3. Import certificate of CA into GlassFish keystore:

   ```
   $ keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias AwesomeCA -file ~/AwesomeCA.crt -keystore keystore.jks
   Enter keystore password: changeit
   Certificate was added to keystore
   [Storing keystore.jks]
   ```
4. Import obtained SSL certificate into GlassFish keystore:

   ```
   $ keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias myAlias -file ~/myCertificate.crt -keystore keystore.jks
   Enter keystore password: changeit
   Enter key password for <myAlias>: myPassword
   Certificate reply was installed in keystore
   [Storing keystore.jks]
   ```
5. At this moment error `java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key` would occur during GlassFish startup because you have different keystore password and alias key password. To prevent this error you need to execute:

   ```
   $ keytool -keypasswd -alias myAlias -new changeit -keystore keystore.jks
   Enter keystore password: changeit
   Enter key password for <myAlias>: myPassword
   ```
6. Change default alias (`s1as`) in GlassFish to your `myAlias`:

   ```
   $ asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.cert-nickname=myAlias
   ```
7. (Optional) You can change default SSL port (`8181`) in GlassFish to well known `443`:

   ```
   $ asadmin set server.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.http-listener-2.port=443
   ```
8. Restart GlassFish

Answer (score 1):

For Glassfish 4.x you can follow [this Comodo Guide](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1123/66/certificate-installation-glassfish-4x)

*Here is the [web archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018193918/https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1123/66/certificate-installation-glassfish-4x) if link expires.*

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I wrote a guide in portuguese [here](https://gist.github.com/douglasjunior/9cb1ff566823a37f07e72aa2c34ab0fb), I will translate to english and write here in SO.