# Where to import certificate for glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, ssl-certificate, keytool

I have an Ubuntu server on which glassfish is installed, now I want to import an certificate (.cer) into java using `keytool` command. To get path of java used by glassfish I opened file asenv.conf and I get path from `AS_JAVA=/usr/local/jdk1.6.0_45/jre`.

So using keytool command I have installed certificates but still I am getting `unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Where to import certificate?

Comment: The certificate is for the URL to which one of my web application in glassfish is requesting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [import ssl certificate in Glassfish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860289/import-ssl-certificate-in-glassfish)